Why can we formally test the relevance assumption of instrument variable?
I saw in my old slides about IV, the professor said we cannot test exclusion assumption of IV but we can test relevance assumption of IV. His argument for not able to test exclusion is:

$y=\beta_1 x_1 +\beta_2 x_2+\gamma z + u$ if z is not independent from u, then you cannot test exclusion requirement by doing this regression and argue with $\gamma=0$ since $cov(z,u)\ne 0$ would bias the estimate of $\gamma$

Meanwhile he said you can test for relevance assumption by:

$x_1=\eta x_2+\lambda z+v$, if $\eta $ is significantly different from 0, we have relevance requirement satisifed

However, isn't the second also suffer from endogeneity problem? so if z is not independent from v, but correlated with x_2, then $\eta $ would be biased. If we observe non-zero gamma, it could be there is an upward bias, z itself does not have any relationship with x if the bias is not there.

I think your notation here is overloaded. The coefficients in the two equations are represented by the same Greek letters, but they are quite different, which complicates any discussion of identification. I would rewrite the question to make it clear what you are interested in.

@dimitriy you are right, i just changed it

In the linear setting, if $Z$ is a valid instrument, the relevance condition mandates that $\operatorname{cov}(Z,X_1 \mid X_2) \neq 0$. This can be tested by fitting a model with $X_1$ as the dependent variable and $Z$ and $X_2$ as predictors, and then examining the significance of $Z$ ($\gamma$ in your second lineal model). All variables in this model are observed and present in the data, so the task is feasible. It is not concerning if $\gamma$ is biased for the true effect of $Z$ on $X_1$ conditional on $X_2$, because the condition, in the linear setting, only requires correlation, not an unbiased estimation of a causal effect for this stage.
Conversely, the exclusion restriction requires that $\operatorname{cov}(Z,U) = 0$, where $U$ includes the unexplained components of $Y$ not accounted for by $X_1$ and $X_2$, such as potential latent confounders. If we suspect the presence of a latent confounder in the system, $U$ is not fully observed, making it unfeasible to directly test $\operatorname{cov}(Z,U) = 0$ due to the unobserved nature of $U$.
